# bash script to run ./configure from sudo

Tags: bash, configure

I am using GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10) on Solaris and trying to write a bash script to configure/compile sudo after doing a few other items. Essentially I want to be able to have operators run this script so they can install sudo from source by just running this script and not having to worry about running ./configure with options and make, etc..

It appears it works up until the config.status libtool part and then it dies with:

```
: creating pathnames.h config.status: pathnames.h is unchanged config.status: executing libtool commands
./install_sudo.sh: line 55: configure:: command not found
```

install_sudo.sh is my script which basically just untar's sudo and sets up the path. It then runs a function ConfigureSudo:

here is the script now that is not working with the above error:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
Unpack(){
SRCA="sudo-1.8.7.tar.gz"
SRCB="sudo-1.8.7.tar"

if [ -f $PWD/$SRCA ]; then
 echo "sudo source appears to be here!"
 `/usr/bin/gunzip "$SRCA"`
 `/usr/bin/tar xf "$SRCB"`
  else
 echo "Check your source file."
fi
}

SetupPath(){
echo "Setting up path to use included Solaris software..."
echo "Current PATH is $PATH"
PATH=/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:/usr/sfw/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin:$PATH
echo "Now set to $PATH"
}

ConfigureSudo(){
dir="/tmp/sudo-1.8.7"
arg1="--prefix=/usr/local"
arg2="--sysconfdir=/etc"
arg3="--localstatedir=/var/run/sudo"
arg4="--with-pam"
arg5="--with-timedir=/var/lib/sudo"
cmd=configure

$($dir/$cmd $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5)
}

Unpack
SetupPath
ConfigureSudo
```

Any help to get past with is greatly appreciated.
TIA!
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$($dir/$cmd $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5)
```

You don't need to place that inside process substitution I think. Its output would be executed as well. You should also quote your variables properly.

```
"$dir/$cmd" "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3" "$arg4" "$arg5"
```

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be to place the line:

```
set -x
```

immediately after the shebang line (line #1) so that commands are echoed before being executed.

That will show you any problematic expansions that are happening and may lead you to the problem.

You *may* also need to put it at the start of each function, I can't remember whether it carries forward into functions or not. But try it at the top of the script first.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and everything expands properly so it does not appear to be an issue with the actual script, but more of a problem with the libtool piece and configure.